# How can I space UITextField leading and training edges in a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have two UITextFields in a vertical UIStackView. I want their leading and trailing edges to be 20 points away from the edge of the UIStackView. However I cannot figure how to do this without conflicting constraints. The conflicting constraint errors don't make sense to me as they say that I have two constraints that conflict but as you can see I only added one constraint for each UITextField.

Here is my situation in images:

[image: This is my view and constraint layout.]

[image: I want the two UITextFields leading and trailing edges within the UIStackView to be 20 points away from the edge of the UIStackView.]

[image: These are the conflicting constraint issues.]

Comment: You cannot do it that way... You'll need to set the text field constraints relative to the super view of the stack view (and don't set the stack view to "fill").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option...

Embed your `UITextField`s inside `UIView`s and let the stack view stretch the Views to the full width. Then constrain the text fields to their "containing" views.

Adding a Height constraint to the text fields, and then "pinning" the top and bottom to the top / bottom of the containing view will also get the view to "auto-size" to the heigh of the text field.

[image]

For clarity, I set the background color of the containing views to "Cantaloupe" so you can see them, and the blue rectangle is just a plain `UIView` (as you showed in the Document Outline in your image), with a Height constraint of 80.